# Adding an admin section in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring web project, which needs an admin section. I assumed this part would be easy and that I would have issues with security, but I can't even point to a /admin/ section.

I have the following in my dispatcher-servelet.xml to map JSP files to controllers:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controller.admin"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

There is now a folder labelled "admin" in /WEB-INF/jsp/ and there I have adminindex.jsp. I also have the following in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>admin pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administration Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>eCommerceAdmin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <!--  <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>-->
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

When I try and access

localhost:8080/NewWebsite/admin/adminindex.htm

, I get

> Access to the requested resource has been denied
>
> INFO: ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@44d1bd08')

I have no trouble accessing

localhost:8080/NewWebsite/index.htm, and I would also like to have an auto redirect for the admin folder like it is with the root folder. I.E going to

localhost:8080/NewWebsite/ directs to index.htm.

Any help would be great.

Comment: it would be easies to answer if you supply more code here. Only this much setting won't help. Are you adding ROLE to your user like ROLE_ADMIN??

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what else to add. I have added the entire contents of web.xml, but I am unsure how to adapt it to include an admin role?

Comment: where are you adding `eCommerceAdmin` this role to your spring `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` ???

Comment: I think this was a previous failed attempt, which I forgot to remove. Do you know where I should be adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIrst you need to validate the user?isn't it? Otherwise how your application would recognise wheter ADMIN is trying to access or normal USER? 
Before you do this remove `security-constraint` from your **web.xml**
So Add spring authentication in your app.
First Create a pojo class to have a list of `GrantedAuthority` which should implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` . Below is a sample:

```
public class YourPojo implements UserDetails{


    /** The authorities. */
    //This collection will have eCommerceAdmin
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    /** The username. */
    public String username;

    /** The account non expired. */
    public boolean accountNonExpired;

    /** The credentials non expired. */
    public boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    /** The enabled. */
    public boolean enabled;

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2342376103893073629L;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getAuthorities()
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getPassword()
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#getUsername()
     */
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return accountNonExpired;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isCredentialsNonExpired()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails#isEnabled()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }


    /**
     * Sets the authorities.
     *
     * @param authorities the new authorities
     */
    public void setAuthorities(Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the username.
     *
     * @param username the new username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the account non expired.
     *
     * @param accountNonExpired the new account non expired
     */
    public void setAccountNonExpired(boolean accountNonExpired) {
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the account non locked.
     *
     * @param accountNonLocked the new account non locked
     */
    public void setAccountNonLocked(boolean accountNonLocked) {
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the credentials non expired.
     *
     * @param credentialsNonExpired the new credentials non expired
     */
    public void setCredentialsNonExpired(boolean credentialsNonExpired) {
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the enabled.
     *
     * @param enabled the new enabled
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Below is the HTTP tag that you require.

```
<!-- to use Spring security tags -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
<http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>        
<http auto-config="false">      
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="eCommerceAdmin" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />     

        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>           
    </http>
```

Now define your authentication provider.

```
<bean id="customeAuthProvider" class="your.auth.provider.class">
  </bean>

   <authentication-manager >        
        <authentication-provider ref="customeAuthProvider" ></authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

This `customeAuthProvider` should implement `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider`.

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)authentication;
        String username = userToken.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
          //Do whatevr you want with the credentials
         //Then populate the authorities for this credential
         YourPojo user=new YourPojo ();
         user.setUserName("add username");
        //set other details
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        //if user is admin add the below line
        GrantedAuthorityImpl grantedAuthorityImpl = new GrantedAuthorityImpl("eCommerceAdmin");
       //Add other authorities as applicable like 'user' etc.
       user.setAuthorities(grantedAuthorityList);
       return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, user.getAuthorities());
```

FYR you can reference security xml file in your web.xml as below..and also your web.xml should have spring security filters.

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/your-applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/your-spring-security.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You need spring security dependencies as well..if you are using Maven for your project add the following dependencies else you can manually download these jars and proceed.

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you are good to go..
FYR go through [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/)

Comment: Wow this is really good, thank you. I have a few questions if I may..Does it matter where I put YourPojo class? Are the HTTP tags and beans meant to be placed in applicationContext? And does it matter where I put customeAuthProvider? I haven't had a chance to try this out yet but I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: No need to thank me. You can Upvote the answer and later if it worked(it should if configured correctly) then can accept the answer. Now your answers: You can put `YourPjojo` anywhere.Same goes for Authentication provider too but you should provide correct package details in the bean.. The http tags and beans should not be in `applicationContext` you can place it in sosme other xml file and attach it in your **web.xml**..

Comment: how do I include UserDetails into my project? Netbeans is having a fit at the moment. YourPojo is complaining and I am also not sure how to include the new XML files. Do they get referenced in dispatcher at all?

Comment: UserDetails is spring's [UserDetails](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) interface...Are you not using applicationContext.xml?How are you referencing that in web.xml?The same way add your new xml too..Have added few more code...see the edit

Comment: Let me know if this is enough..There are plenty of examples in the link i have shared too...

Comment: I think I am just being stupid, but my project is not a Spring Maven project. It is just Spring MVC. I tried downloading the hello world example, but I dont have Maven installed on Netbeans or something. Is there any way I can incorporate this in my webApp without Maven?

Comment: How do you build your App?? Is it ant build? Then just add these jars and it should work.

Comment: I think so yeah. To simplify things, I have created a new Spring Web project and copied the files from the example in the link you sent me. However, I get the following error: WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Mar 13 13:14:31 GMT 2013]; root of context hierarchy

Comment: You can see [this](http://codenddebug.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-create-admin-section-using.html) ..you will see a detailed explanation...and sources are also there. :)

Comment: Wow another great answer thanks! There is an issue with permissions when I try and download the sources, I am guessing they are yours?

Comment: Thanks, got it, it involves Maven though. I Have been having trouble incorporating the rest of my project into a Maven project and have had a lot of compatibility issues mainly with JDBC code. Can't I just change my Spring Web app to have security?

Comment: Why not? Add the spring secuirty jar alone..that should be fine..Check in the pom file whatever jars i have mentioned for sring security..

Comment: I tried that with the last link and had all sorts of complications. I don't like Maven at all. This seems highly complicated for a simple admin form...

Comment: You don't know the power of maven..thats why you don't like it..just a simple advantage is that you dnt hve to carry our jars.you can download it anywhere in the world.. :)

Comment: Lol yeah maybe. Well your answer is very well written and will help many people so thanks a lot. Sorry for my idiocy in trying to understand! I will work with this and have a play.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your prefix to WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the viewresolver so the info you provide isn't sufficient to answer your question. Please show a bit more config esp you security configuration.

Besides your question. The component-scan on controller.admin shouldnt be necessary cause the first one will scan it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have included the rest of web.xml, how could I include an admin role and possible assign it login details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using spring security, then you can configure spring security role system to control access. Below is a snippet taken form one of my applications, as you can see  the /admin path requires the caller to have a role of Admin. Spring security is a bit complex to setup, but once setup it works very well.

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" >

    <!-- public resources that everyone should be able to access -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login"       access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/error" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js"        access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.jsp"       access="denyAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"     access="hasRole('admin')" />

    </session-management>

</http>
```