# Change Form Action Name Dynamically In Spring Controller

Tags: java, html, spring

Hi i am attempting to change form action in spring controller when hits different url in browser.

When i hit url : http://localhost:8080/DEMO/shas/getExtLogin?key=11 Then action is appending in form tag as action="/DEMO/shas/getExtLogin?key=11".

But i need to change action as action="/DEMO/admin/" in LoginController.java getExternalLogin() method, when hit url : http://localhost:8080/DEMO/shas/getExtLogin?key=11

My jsp Code : login.jsp

```
<form:form id="login" commandName="loginDO" clas="form-header">
```

My Java Code : LoginController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getExtLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getExternalLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String extInd = request.getParameter("extInd");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("extInd", extInd);
        return new ModelAndView("jsp/login").addObject("loginDO", new LoginDO());

    }
```

Is there any way to change form action in spring controller while returning ModelAndView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an admin section in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302699/adding-an-admin-section-in-spring)

Comment: I need to set in java file instead of config in xml's.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by Adding action="${addUrl}" attribute in form tag.

```
<form:form id="login" commandName="loginDO" action="${addUrl}" clas="form-header">
```

And modified below method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getExtLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getExternalLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String extInd = request.getParameter("extInd");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("extInd", extInd);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("addUrl", "/DEMO/admin/");
    mav.addObject("loginDO", new LoginDO());
    mav.setViewName("auth/crclogin");
    return mav;
}
```